# `s` doesn't trigger surrounding, but substitute (`cl`)

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vim-surround

I installed [this vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) configuration (including plugins), and saw that vim-surround was included. With that, the surround-readme tells me I can use things like `ds"` to delete surrounding quotes.

However, `s` triggers a substitute of the character under the cursor + placing me in insert mode (`:help s` says `s` is a synonym for `cl`).

I can't find this referenced in the config, so I'm wondering why I can't use surround?

Sorry if this is very stupid, new to Vim...

If it matters, this is the output of `vim --version` for me:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep 12 2016 17:17:45)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-2
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     -gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        -toolbar
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xpm
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: clang   -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.0_1/lib/perl5/5.24.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc -F/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks -framework Python   -lruby.2.3.0 -lobjc -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib
```

Comment: It isn't `d`, `s`! It's `ds`. You should type `ds` so fast and then `"` ( or any other surrounding charachter).

Comment: Don't use someone else's vimrc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `s` *is* a synonym for `cl`. tpope/vim-surround does *not* change this, it adds new operators. The full list of operators that vim-surround adds is

- `ds<foo>` which the mnemonic is (D)elete (S)urrounding foo. For example, `ds"`, or `ds(`
- `cs<foo><bar>` which the mnemonic is (C)hange (S)urrounding foo to bar. For example, to go from single to double quotes, use `cs"'`

and lastly

- `ys<motion><foo>` which doesn't have a great mnemonic. You can just think of it as "surround". This one will surround the `<motion>` with foo. For example, to surround 2 words with parenthesis, use `ys2w)` (or use `(`, both of them work, but subtly different)

As well as this, it provides the visual mode mapping `S` which is just (S)urround the visual selection.

If pressing `ds"` doesn't work for you, you could be typing it too slowly. For example, `d<pause>s<pause>"` will be seen by vim as `d<timeout>` which cancels the `d` operator, followed by `s"` which deletes one character, puts you in insert mode and inserts a `"`. To fix this, you must type it faster.

If you don't want to type it that quickly, or if you can't, you could also try adjusting `timeoutlen` or `timeout`. `timeoutlen` changes how long vim waits before a command times out (in milliseconds). So you could set it to

```
:set timeoutlen=2500
```

for 2.5 seconds, or whatever you want. Or you could do

```
:se notimeout
```

which makes it so no commands *ever* time out, no matter how long you wait.